# Closed subspace of Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open and bounded set. Let $\partial \Omega=\Gamma_{D}\cup\Gamma_{N}\cup \Gamma_{C}$ (disjoint). Consider

$V=\{v\in H^{1}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)\, | v=0 \, \text{on}\, \Gamma_{D}\}$.

Why is $V$ a closed subspace of $H^{1}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: I think that $v=0\, \text{on} \, \Gamma_{D}$ must be naturally understood in the sense of trace operator which is continuous.  So the inverse image of closed subset is transofmed into a closed subset. Do you find it correct?